# Distributed identifiers over network

Tags: c++, networking, synchronization, distributed, identity

I need to create a distributed network of objects talking to each other based on an identifier (auto-generated, numeral, re-usable). How can I create objects on each node of the graph without creating collisions?

For the moment, I'm using a *master* node to allocate IDs, but this solution involves asynchronous creation of objects on the other nodes, which I'd like to remove. Especially because the application is meant to be real-time, so RDBMS are a no-go.

I'm aware this is a rather classic distributed computing issue, but I'm probably lacking vocabulary to search properly.

TCP is the only protocol I can use, and the network is subject to latency. In case it matters, I'm working in C++, but I'm looking for an algorithm, not a library.

Answer (score 2):

You may like using [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s as identifiers, they are unique by design so you won't need any extra algorithmic support.

Comment: This might be working, but I'm worried about the size overhead. In the current implementation, my identifiers fit in 16 bits.

Comment: it will be 8x increase compared to what you use

Answer (score 2):

Instead of master node allocating an ID at a time, you could have it allocate a block or a range of IDs at a time to each node.  Each node then allocates IDs from within that block as needed.

When a node becomes low on IDs, it requests another block from the master.  This way nodes can create objects asynchronously and still have guaranteed unique IDs.

I am assuming when the object is deleted, the ID is returned to the pool for re-use.

Another option if you do not want the master node to be in charge of distributing IDs is to use something like ethernet MAC address or IP address appended with a counter to make up the ID.  This requires that no duplicate IP or MAC addresses show up on the network. This ID would be larger than 16 bits.

However, if all the nodes are on the same network, e.g. IP address AA.BB.CC.DD, then you could use DD as the first 8 bits and then next 8 bits as the counter.  This would only give 256 IDs per node, which may not be sufficient.  If subnet is smaller, then the bits available for the counter obviously go up and perhaps that is enough to solve the problem.

Comment: I like the idea, but that's putting too much responsibility about entropy on the repartition of objects. In my application, a node may be responsible for the creation of all the objects, or each node may create a single object. Maybe adjusting the size of the identifier is the trick (to 32 bits or so).

Comment: Good point.  I don't know why I assumed that object creation would be evenly spread across the nodes. Going to 32 bits might allow using high order bits for hardware serial number or something unique to node and the rest of bits could be date + time or a persistent counter.

Answer (score 0):

Just create it random. with random values of 128 bit, the chances of a collision is so small you can assume it's zero. On a 128 bit uuid space the probability of a collision is 2^64 (birthday paradox)

Obviously you need a good entropy source, the classic `sha1(time(NULL))` is a no-go ;)

more important: if nodes choose their UUID at random there's absolutely no need for a central coordinator which create and give UUIDs to the nodes. Each node create its own UUID by itself.